# add applications (menu item) to windows phone 7 context menu

Tags: windows-phone-7

is there a possibility that i should be able to add some menu item in windows phone 7.
e.g.
when i select options of a picture i want to add some "Do this" menu item in tose options.. and on that option selection one of my app would trigger some event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in the current API. The API is quite limited at the moment. I do believe Microsoft has said that future versions will expose more functionality.

Comment: i thought so... but this sort of functionality was suppose to be the part of current relase...

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for what Context Menu offers if I've understood your question.

Brad Tutterow offers a walkthrough here.

[WP7 Tip of the Day: Silverlight Toolkit: Context Menus](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/02/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Context-Menus.aspx)

Comment: i.e. to create your own menu in your running program... no to extend existing OS provided menu.

Answer (score 0):

The [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) contains a context menu but you should also consider using the menu in the application bar as this would provide continuity with how the built in pictures app  (hub) implements a menu for actions on images.

Comment: i.e. to create application bar or your own menu in your application not OS provided one.